# Is it possible to configure a WCF service client to throw a custom FaultException?

Tags: wcf, error-handling, wcfserviceclient

I was wondering if it was possible to configure a WCF service client to use a custom type instead of FaultException when throwing faults.  The custom type would inherit from FaultException, but also have some additional details about the error.

The reason I want to use a custom FaultException is so I can store a GUID from the SOAP Header which is otherwise lost.

I know I could manually catch and rethrow any faults my service client returns, but that's flimsy.  I have no way of guaranteeing future developers will do the same.

I've thought about subclassing the generated service client class and putting the error handling in there, but that generates a lot of work whenever the target service changes.

So, is it possible to configure a WCF service client to throw a custom FaultException type for Faults?

Comment: Have you looked at [Fault Contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752208.aspx)s?

Comment: If my understanding of FaultContracts is correct then they're defined on the Service side.  In my particular case I don't have access to the service side.  I'm trying to take the current Faults and embellish them with SOAP header data (mainly because I can't influence what is in the actual Fault thrown by the service).  Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own IErrorHandler implementation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx

Override ProvideFault and then do conversion from regular exceptions (including plain FaultException) to your own custom based `FaultException<T>`, where T is your own type that you can define to include custom properties.

After that, you have to register your implementation of IErrorHandler as service behavior, either in code or in web/app config.

Comment: Sounds promising.  Thanks.  I'll give it a shot tomorrow at work.